# What does そういうこと mean in this exchange

Tags: meaning

I'm struggling to understand what Amane means when she says そういうこと in
「**そういうことよ**。まったく、メル友の十人や二十人くらい、いるでしょ？」. I'm assuming failing to understand this is what is also causing me confusion in understanding how that follows on to the second part of what she says "まったく、メル友の十人や二十人くらい、いるでしょ？" in the following exchange:

Context: Tomoyuki has been living in Tokyo for a while but he has come back to town, whilst he was in Tokyo he was in regular contact with Amane, however Megumi did not know this. Amane, realizing that she has screwed up by mentioning this (she knows that Both Tomoyuki and Megumi like each other) she quickly tries to remedy the situation before Megumi gets the wrong idea.

> 天音「ええ。智之とメールしてた時の印象と、恵に聞いてた話にズレがあって」
>
> 恵「メール？　ねえ、智之くん。天音ちゃんとメールしてたの？」
>
> 智之「あれ？　言ってなかったっけ？」
>
> 恵「う、うん……」
>
> 智之「天音とは、たまにメールでやり取りしてたんだよ」
>
> 恵「え、そうなの？」
>
> 天音「あっちゃあ……」
>
> 智之「うごっ！？」
>
> 天音「友達として、よ。東京のことも気になってたしね」
>
> 天音「そうよね、智之」
>
> 智之「あ、ああ。俺もこっちのこと知りたかったしな」
>
> 恵「そ、そうなんだ……天音ちゃんと……」
>
> 智之「仕方ないだろ。おまえ、そういうの苦手なんだし」
>
> 恵「うう……それは、そうだけど……」
>
> 天音「気になるなら、やりとりしたメール、後で見せてあげるから」
>
> 恵「ええっ！？　で、でも……」
>
> 天音「**そういうことよ**。まったく、メル友の十人や二十人くらい、いるでしょ？」
>
> 智之「俺はいない……あがっ！？」
>
> 足の甲に鋭い痛みが走る。
>
> 天音「気にしないの。それに、恵がしたいなら私が教えてあげるから、毎日でもすればいいでしょ？」
>
> 恵「う、うん。そうだね」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amane wants to make Megumi understand that her mail exchange with Tomoyuki while he was in Tokyo was nothing more than friends keeping in touch (she wanted to know more about Tokyo, and he wanted to hear updates from -- what I assume to be -- his home town).

Amane's 「そういうことよ」 here means "that's how it is (implied: so you don't need to worry)”, where "that" is the above-described situation she is trying to convey to Megumi.

To reassure Megumi further, she follows up by prodding Tomoyuki with the question "You probably have around 10-20 mail friends, right?" -- a fairly strong hint that he respond with "yes" regardless of how many he actually has, in order to demonstrate that Amane being just one of his (supposedly many) mail friends isn't that big of a deal.